# check if the user is logged in

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a Dashboard controller with Route setup as `/Dashboard[/:action][/:id]`

I do not want to check `$auth->hasIdentity()` in index , edit, add, delete Actions of my 
Dashboard controller, I want a detect that from the top level. After reading many blogs 
and documentation I found `getControllerConfig()` is the right place for any initial 
setup a controller may need.

Unfortunately I can not do `redirect()` from within `getControllerConfig()` function
I have already checked `ZfcUser` but that is too much for my small scenario.

Can some one throw light on this and thanks.

Comment: Is it really too much? You can easily disable the registration and outside of that, any solution would pretty much just copy the needed parts of ZfcUser. You could combine ZfcUser and BjyAuthorize to easily block the resources for a logged in user

Comment: thanks Sam but again if there was no ZfcUser and BjyAuthorize then how would one do it. ? BTW both of them check hasIdentity() inside their controllers where he want to do it before that

Comment: Event i tried attaching on MVC:EVENT_ROUTE but that doesn't get called.

Comment: I'd override onDispatch method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best solutions from the zf2 forums to handle the request from the very top level and do the redirect before even initializing your controller logic.

Secondly through this technique you do not require to check $auth->hasIndentity() inside 
your controller anyAction() which gives you piece of mind working on some special 
route where you want to make certain the user must be logged in. i.e. /Dashboard

That works for me i hope it helps all.

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $serviceManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
    $path = $e->getRequest()->getUri()->getPath();

    if(strripos($path, 'Dashboard') !== false) {
        $authService = $serviceManager->get('MyApp\Authentication\Service');
        if (!$authService->hasIdentity()) {
            $e->getResponse()
                ->setStatusCode(302)
                ->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('location', '/path/to/login');
            return $e->getResponse();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use the 2.1 branch there is a controller plugin that will do the work for you. Inside a controller just do:

```
$identity = $this->identity()
```